# Rails 4 controller query to validate whether or not license is valid

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am in a bit of a bind and not too sure where to start with this..

I have a model that stores a users Drivers License info and it is nested to an Admin user, to be able to create it from the admin show page.

what I am looking to achieve is a query that validates todays date against the expiry date of the license. And then use that information to send a notification to the proper person. i will re use this to send a notification one month out that the license is about to expire...

My biggest problem is how to actually query this, i am not sure if a cron job is in order or if this can be done in the controller directly? I've read a few articles where it was either or but I've never done a cron job in the past.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider [sidetiq gem](https://github.com/tobiassvn/sidetiq)

It's workd together with [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) and allows to perform some periodic jobs.

That's pretty simple to implement and manage.

Also you can give a try to [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) but it's just a cron wrapper.
I strongly recommend to use sidetiq.

**General approach**

Just implement some daily job which will:

- collect drivers licences you need to notify users about
- notify users with any prefferied way :)

Also please note that all that jobs will run in background.

You can find more info in sidekiq and sidetiq wikis.

Comment: This is awesome! i just took a look at that gem and seems relatively straight forward!

Comment: @ShawnWilson glad to help you :)